# Change blur filter in modal TitleWindows

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I create several instances of TitleWindow. And added them on stage by `PopUpManager.addPopUp( wnd, root, true );`
But how to change blur of madal state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying the following styles on the window :

```
modalTransparencyBlur
modalTransparency
modalTransparencyColor
modalTransparencyDuration
```

You can also set them globally :

```
    <mx:Style>
        global {
            modalTransparencyBlur: 0;
            modalTransparency: 0.8;
            modalTransparencyColor: black;
            modalTransparencyDuration: 500;
        }
    </mx:Style>
```